# What does butter and honey represent scripturally?

Tags: jesus, isaiah, christology

Isaiah 7:15

> Butter and honey shall he eat, that he may know to refuse the evil, and choose the good.

What is the symbolic meaning of eating butter and honey with respect to knowing and refusing evil?

Comment: "he will indulge in butter and honey until he understands that it is bad and instead choses the good stuff". If so, are we talking about cookies, etc.

Comment: Is that how you stay @Constantthin. Or is this an oxymoron .

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by “stay”, but I do know that butter and honey is fat and sugar, like cookies, ice cream, and chocolate; and contains minute amounts of protein and carbs. And I do know that when the Israelites entered the promised land they left the desert behind.

Comment: @ Constantthin They had a large helping of leviathin (psalm74:14), to cut calories.

Comment: Sure. There was a lot of rushing to and fro when trying to outdo the enemy. Any unwanted kilos must have melted away in a jiffy. Good call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stephen Disraeli has great insights, but then I thought about what Isaiah was describing. It involves a virgin, a small male child, foods he eats (the baby, not Stephen), and choosing good over evil.

Here’s how the Septuagint articulates the verses in context:

> On account of this, the LORD himself will give you a sign — behold the
> virgin [*Parthenos* in Greek] will conceive in the womb, and she shall
> bear a son, and you shall call his name Immanuel. Butter and honey he
> shall eat before he knows to prefer the wicked or to choose the good.
> For before the male child knows good or evil, in resisting persuasion
> of wickedness, he chooses the good and the land shall be abandoned
> which you fear of in front of the two kings. – Isaiah 7:14-16 (APB)

Verse 16 in the Dead Sea scrolls reads

> For before the child knows to refuse evil and choose good, the land
> whose two kings you dread will be abandoned.
> (DSS translation and commentary by Abegg, Flint, & Ulrich)

So how were babies fed before the time of bottles and jars of Gerber? What foods did babies eat?

In much of the developing world today, babies are breast-fed (which results in natural birth control) until about 2-4 years of age. We know from I Kings 3:19 that babies slept with their mothers, presumably getting snacks of breast milk through the night as needed. Breast feeding trails off as the mother supplements the child with soft food (perhaps the honey and curds or butter mentioned in Isaiah) and other food that she thoroughly chews up before squeezing it into her baby’s mouth.

I know, TMI. But that's the reality, which provides context for this passage. Isaiah provides us with detail about the unique nature of this child *before the age of accountability* that everyone familiar with babies would understand.

Comment: @ Dieter Great job. I voted you up and flagged your answer as my favorite. I also had voted up Stephen. The answer you gave is almost exactly what I was going to post myself as an answer. This only came to me after meditating on both your input and Stephen on the verse in Ch.8. My instinct from the beginning, since I have been feeding my on grandsons baby food, led me to the same conclusion. The honey has a long shelf life at room temperature . Without modern canning and refrigeration honey would have been a great " baby food " for a seemed child. This may also reference Jesus' time in Egypt.

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for asking that interesting and provocative question.

Comment: @ Dieter This spell check is killing me. It keeps changing my input.

Comment: +1  -- A good example of the proper use of Occam's razor: the simplest answer is the best.  God gives a sign to Ahaz regarding a threat from the north... a special child named Immanuel will be born, and before he reaches the age of maturity, the Assyrian empire will arise to nullify the threat of the two northern kings.  No special meaning to butter/curds and honey other than that these were the ancient equivalent of today's baby foods.

Answer (score 2):

The RSV reads "He shall eat curds and honey when he knows how to refuse the good and choose the evil". In other words, the knowledge comes first. The AV's implication that the knowledge is the result of the eating is misleading.

As often happems, the explanation of the verse is to be found in the context and situation. It has the effect of defining the time when curds and honey will be available to be eaten. This will happen by the time the child is old enough to know what food it likes and doesn't like. A similar prophecy in the next chapter defines the deadline as "Before the child knows how to call for his father and mother". I think this implies that the time-interval is not much more than a year (I spoke my first words at two and a half years old, but apparently this is unusual).

"Curds and honey will be available" was an exciting promise for Isaiah's immediate audience because they were the starving inhabitants of a besieged city, in danger of being reduced to eating the furniture and each other. When we read the following verses, we see that their salvation is achieved when the besieging armies are chased away, and they can get out into the countryside again. Since curds (or butter) come from milk, this also amounts to a promise of restoration of the "land of milk and honey".

In the original setting, the birth of the child simply sets the clock running towards the deadline being announced in v15. It becomes a prophecy in its own right under the New Testament interpretation. If we want to extend that interpretation to the following verses, it could be in terms of "When Christ is born, he will vanquish our ultimate enemies (sin and death) and enable us to enjoy the milk and honey of the heavenly banquet."

Comment: @ Stephen Disraeli. Prophecy is usually directed toward future audiences. At least Gen.3:15 surely is. I am 4 hrs. Past my sleep time. I am getting incoherent. I will check back tomorrow, but thanks to everyone for your participation.

Comment: Prophecy is addressed in the first instance towards the people of the prophet's own time, this passage being a classic example. The Holy Spirit allows re-interpretation for Christian purposes, especially when the additonal interpretation is endorsed by the New Testament, but the spirit of the original intention remains a useful guide. In this case, for example, the shared theme is "the promise of salvation from your enemies".

Comment: @ Stephen Disraeli I must admit at first I thought this question would not be answered to a high degree of certainty. But the amalgamated effort resulted in an answer I feel a high degree of certainty was achieved. Thank you for your contribution. I upvoted you in appreciation.

Comment: Stephen Disraeli, I especially liked your connection to the two kings *we* dread, sin and death,

Answer (score 1):

Butter is only used three times in the scriptures, and it seems to represent luxury and smoothness. But what is it with honey?

> No grain offering, which you bring near to Yahweh, shall be made with
> leaven, for you shall not offer up in smoke any leaven or any honey as
> an offering by fire to Yahweh. – Leviticus 2:11 (Legacy Standard
> Bible)

Regarding honey, which is kosher and also part of the traditional Jewish Passover meal, I found numerous references and comparisons in the scriptures. Then, I thought, “Well, if leaven is prohibited in burnt offerings for its symbolism, then what about honey? If leaven puffs up, then what does honey do?”

Initially, I thought about honey’s sweetness from the scriptures. But also, maybe that God didn’t want his people to think they were “buttering him up” or deny the bitterness in life before God. Or maybe it was because honey was possibly considered a luxury item.

Next, I checked to see whether honey can easily be burned in an offering (it can), and I checked to see what reasons Jewish rabbis gave for the prohibition of honey (I found their reasons odd, as usual).

Then, I realized that the prohibition against including honey in burnt offerings was given earlier than Samson’s honey in the lion and Solomon’s proverbs. In fact, honey first appears as a commandment in *Torah*. Before Torah was received, the Hebrews who left Egypt were told that the promised land was “a land flowing with milk and honey.” Didn’t manna taste like coriander seed, wafers, and honey?

So, I asked myself, did Egyptians keep bees and what did the Egyptians think of honey? For one thing, the bee was the symbol of the pharaoh of lower Egypt, the Nile delta. But what else I found was amazing! Here are some excerpts from a website article on the subject.

> Honey was used by all classes in Ancient Egypt, indicating that it
> must have been produced on a large scale. It was used for everything
> from sweetening food, to preventing infection by being placed on
> wounds, to paying taxes. One marriage contract has been found which
> states, "I take thee to wife... and promise to deliver to thee yearly
> twelve jars of honey." Honey was exacted as tribute from conquered
> countries; for instance, many jars of honey were paid each year by the
> Retenu tribe of Syria to their Egyptian conqueror, Thothmes II.
>
> Honey and wax were used for religious as well as practical purposes.
> Sacred animals were fed cakes sweetened with honey. Mummies were
> sometimes embalmed in honey, and often sarcophagi were sealed up with
> beeswax. Jars of honey were left in tombs as offerings the dead, to
> give them something to eat in the afterlife . . . when King Tut's tomb
> was opened, a 3,000-year-old jar of honey was found. And because honey
> never spoils, it was still perfectly edible!

Ewww! I have no idea how they tested this.

However, in a ceremonial offering known as the "Opening of the Mouth", Egyptian priests used special instruments to place honey into the mouth of a newly carved statue of a god, or the statue or the mummy of a king or other great noble.

Ah hah!

It seems very likely to me that because honey was frequently used in the Egyptian religion—and the Hebrews would have been well aware of this—that YHVH wanted nothing to do with ceremonial honey! YHVH wanted to make sure that the Hebrews wouldn’t be led to believe that he was a god like all the Egyptian gods. YHVH did not need any help from priests to “open His mouth!”

Comment: @ Dieter Thank you for the contribution. I am scratching my head on this. At first read the context sounds of a frugal, non-indulgent life style of Jesus as a child. Something that would not spoil. John the Baptist ate honey and locusts and wore camel skin. Pieces aren't exactly fitting yet!

Comment: My first impression as well on the 3000 year old honey.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, RHPclass97. It seems to me that this demonstrates two of the factors of hermeneutics:  (1) find context in scriptures, culture, language, other writings, etc. and (2) don't be in a hurry to force-fit anything. Allow questions to remain unanswered while you gather additional context, insights, and inspirations. My next exploration will be to compare translations of Isaiah 7:15 in the Dead Sea Scrolls and in the Septuagint, where the Greek word for curds/butter is used nine times. Then, I'll try to understand what Isaiah is telling us regarding the child and good and evil.

Comment: @ Dieter This is a different question, but related:  Call be lazy, but do you know of a reference material that proves errors in the King James . I have several different translations, but always gravitate back to the KJ. With probably over 20 fairly new translations out there, I find it harder and harder to have an intelligent discussion on topics. I guess I will continue to use my old KJ until I see proof of error. What have you noticed in your hermeneutic research to persuade me otherwise.

Comment: The KJV was and is a beautiful translation. You might want to look into its interesting history, including its similarity to the Geneva Bible (but without its "seditious" margin notes) and the manuscripts from which it was originally translated. All translations are approximations to the original meanings because languages don't map well into each other. Sometimes the language used is archaic and difficult to understand. This applies to all languages, not just English. Personally, I always compare several translations in my studies and often return to literal Hebrew and Greek interlinears.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do use a Strong's Concordance in conjunction with the KJV.

Answer (score 0):

Eating butter and honey is an ancient Hebrew idiom for living the mortal trials of life. Symbolicly you have to suffer the world living under the lost blessings of the covenant (or suffer the curses of that covenant) because you broke the covenant. Christ was born to a broken people that had removed themselves from the true God and worshipped their own cleanliness rather than the God that gave them life. He suffered the trials of life just like us and took our sorrows upon himself and as long as we continue to break the covenants of our fathers we will suffer the same.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/53119)

Answer (score 0):

The passage in question:

> חֶמְאָ֥ה וּדְבַ֖שׁ יֹאכֵ֑ל לְדַעְתּ֛וֹ מָא֥וֹס בָּרָ֖ע וּבָח֥וֹר בַּטּֽוֹב׃

Rashi says that “cream and honey he shall eat” is referring to the land having plenty (Rashi on Isaiah 7:15). These foods would be unavailable during a protracted siege of Jerusalem, so the child of this prophecy eating them would mark the victory of Judah in the Syro-Ephraimite War.